# Node.js with MySQL queries

Tags: mysql, node.js

I'm using MySQL for the first time, and I'm struggling to properly preparing statements and escaping query values. Here's where I'm at:

```
    connection.connect();
        formatDate(function(date){
            var sql = "INSERT INTO coffee_tbl (coffee_name, coffee_type, submission_date) VALUES ?";
            var inserts = [req.param('name'), req.param('type'), date];
            var queryString = mysql.format(sql, inserts);
            console.log(queryString)
            connection.query(queryString, function(err, results){ 
            if(err) serverError(res, err); 
            else{ 
            res.redirect('/view_coffee'); 
           }
        });
    });


    connection.end();
```

I'm using the 'mysql' node.js module by felixge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `?` per value.  Also, be sure to use a connection pool.

```
formatDate(function(date){
  var sql = [
    "INSERT INTO coffee_tbl SET",
    " coffee_name=?",
    ",coffee_type=?",
    ",submission_date=?"
    ].join('');
  var inserts = [req.param('name'), req.param('type'), date];
  pool.getConnection(function(err, connection) {
    if(err) return console.error(err);
    connection.query(sql, inserts, function(err, results) {
      connection.release();
      if(err) return console.error(err);
      res.redirect('/view_coffee');
    });
  });
});
```

To setup a connection pool:

```
var pool = mysql.createPool({
  host: process.env.MYSQL_HOST,
  user: process.env.MYSQL_USER,
  password: process.env.MYSQL_PASS,
  database: process.env.MYSQL_NAME,
  connectionLimit: 8
});
```

Use environment variables for your mysql authentication information so as to not commit authentication information to a repo.

Comment: Yeah, I read about connection pools in the documentation...could you possibly elaborate on what that entails?

Comment: Also, what is the differences between using SET and VALUES in the query

Comment: The difference between SET and VALUES is just alternative ways to accomplish the same thing.  I find SET to be a little easier to work with when inserting a single record.

Answer (score 0):

You only have one placeholder in your `sql` var, but you are trying to pass three values in your `inserts` var. You want to modify your `sql` var to have three placeholder like this:

```
var sql = "INSERT INTO coffee_tbl (coffee_name, coffee_type, submission_date) VALUES (?, ?, ?)";
```